# Keep loadnig .\gradlew build

Tags: javascript, java, build.gradle

I'm trying to build a project in Intelligence Idea and I can't figure out why it doesn't tell me built successfully and I see the same picture.

```
> Task :buildFront
yarn run v1.22.18
$ webpack --config webpack.prod.js
Hash: 210d43851b66801516c3
Version: webpack 4.17.2
Time: 9282ms
Built at: 29.03.2022 16:12:25
  Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
main.js  933 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
Entrypoint main [big] = main.js
  [6] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
 [15] ./node_modules/vue-style-loader/lib/addStylesClient.js + 1 modules 6.71 KiB {0} [built]
      |    2 modules
 [84] ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/main/resources/js/pages/MessageList.vue?vue&type=style&
index=0&lang=css& 1.52 KiB {0} [built]
 [85] ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/main/resources/js/pages/Auth.vue?vue&type=style&index=0
&id=50d726d2&scoped=true&lang=css& 1.57 KiB {0} [built]
 [86] ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/main/resources/js/pages/Profile.vue?vue&type=style&inde
x=0&id=78329822&scoped=true&lang=css& 1.58 KiB {0} [built]
 [87] ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/main/resources/js/pages/Subscriptions.vue?vue&type=styl
e&index=0&id=4e392c3c&scoped=true&lang=css& 1.59 KiB {0} [built]
 [88] ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/main/resources/js/pages/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&
lang=css& 1.49 KiB {0} [built]
[335] got (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [built]
[354] ./src/main/resources/js/pages/MessageList.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 648 bytes {0} [built]
[356] ./src/main/resources/js/pages/Auth.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=50d726d2&scoped=true&lang=css& 682 bytes {0} [built]
[358] ./src/main/resources/js/pages/Profile.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=78329822&scoped=true&lang=css& 688 bytes {0} [built]
[360] ./src/main/resources/js/pages/Subscriptions.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=4e392c3c&scoped=true&lang=css& 700 bytes {0} [built]
[391] ./src/main/resources/js/pages/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 632 bytes {0} [built]
[392] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/main/resources/js/pages/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 343 bytes {0} [built] 
[395] ./src/main/resources/js/main.js + 81 modules 205 KiB {0} [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/main.js 885 bytes [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/api/resource.js 84 bytes [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/router/router.js 581 bytes [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/util/ws.js 810 bytes [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/pages/App.vue 1.14 KiB [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/store/store.js 11 KiB [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/pages/MessageList.vue 1.19 KiB [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/pages/Auth.vue 1.2 KiB [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/pages/Profile.vue 1.22 KiB [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/pages/Subscriptions.vue 1.25 KiB [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/pages/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=1ac9ef67& 219 bytes [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/pages/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 396 bytes [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/api/messages.js 484 bytes [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/api/comment.js 162 bytes [built]
      | ./src/main/resources/js/pages/MessageList.vue?vue&type=template&id=235202ea& 227 bytes [built]
      |     + 67 hidden modules
    + 381 hidden modules
<===----------> 27% EXECUTING [30s]
> :buildFront
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.github.node-gradle.node" version "3.1.0"
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.node-gradle.node'

group = 'letscode'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

task buildFront(type: YarnTask) {
    args = ['build']
}

yarn_install.dependsOn(yarn_cache_clean)
buildFront.dependsOn(yarn_install)
processResources.dependsOn(buildFront)

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    annotationProcessor ('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22')
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.1.9.RELEASE'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I tried:

1. write in the terminal .\gradlew build but the same message is out, only it still continued to load.
2. Check imports in files. Because of this, lines starting with error disappeared from the log, but in general it did not help me.
3. Search in Google, but for some reason my error arose only for people who work on the android studio and their's advices did not help me.

Comment: How long did you give the script to run?

Comment: 36 min.........